# Complexe table/grid layout in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a view that will look like this 
[image]

Where each UI are textview, or button. I been working on for 5 hours with no proper result. I try TableLayout, and a gridLayout. I'm out of idea.

Comment: the image url is not working

Comment: weird it seem to work for me.. and now ?

Comment: nope, still not :/ receiving 503

Comment: @JCDecary You can use GridLayout

Comment: @Krish i try, but even if i put layout_columnSpan the first view was taking all the width

Comment: @JCDecary Please check my answer. It is not complete, But you can refer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GridLayout from the v7 support library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.1'
```

Refer this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- 2nd -->

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="4"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- 2nd -->
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <!-- 3rd -->
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_rowSpan="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- 3rd -->

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <!-- 3rd -->
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="5"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Great you were missing 
                app:layout_rowWeight="3". but it work i forgot to use the V7 thank you